# Solar panels not charging batteries

Tags: voltage-regulator

Please help or assist in my charging issues.

Firstly I am running 5, 200W 24V panels which are wired in parrael with all panels fused.
Solar regulator is PWM 50 amp unit.
Battery bank, I am running 4, 200 amp batteries wired to produce 24v.
Inverter / charger unit, rated at 3000 watt.
Cable from panels to battery bank is three fase Orange power cable which I believe is rated at 10mm which given there are 5, cables I have two cables linked up for positive and same for negative so should have overall rating of 20mm.
Length of cables from panels to regulatior is around 30 metres.

Voltage test just after panel was 42 v and same voltage tested just before regulatior 30 meters away from panels.

Charging issue, batteries will charge through inverter/ charger powered via generator but not through solar, regulator has been chaged over but with replacement unit still doing the same and not charging.

Regulator specs, 12 /24v ,  50amp
Low voltage connection 25.2v which batteries have been as low as 24v

Question, if each solar panel is rated at 10amp x 5 = 50amp , being the regulator is only rated at 50amp would or could this be slightly undersized ?

Any help would be much appreciated as my Melbourne supplier is being of no help

Comment: I don't suppose you can provide us with model number for the solar regulator?

Comment: 90 meters, perhaps voltage drop, when under load, can you post diagram of system?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that something is wrong with your regulator.

The first possibly is your supplier gave you a charger intended for a 12V system instead of 24V. Or: you're have a 12V / 24V regulator that is set to 12V mode.

Do you have an oscilloscope available? Look at the DC power supply going into the input of the regulator and make sure that there isn't oscillation present.

Comment: Regulatior can be 12 /24v and supplier has given me another unit to try with same results.regarding supply to regulatior I have disconnected before reg and tested with multi meter with showing same voltage as just after panels.

Comment: That's why I think that it's the regulator.  The solar panels appear to be fine and you have said that the batteries charge just fine from the inverter/charger.  Not much else in the system.

Comment: It's worth looking at the regulator again to see if in fact it's configured for 12V batteries.  That would match the symptoms you are mentioning.

Comment: @Darrenc - "Regulatior can be 12 /24v ". OK, so which way have you got it set up? Are you sure?